# How to style style for different routes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am making an application with three Routers: localhost/login and localhost/admin,
localhost
Different styles.css set for each route
When imported in different js files of different styles.css, they are superimposed on the same page. How do I restrict styles to a single route?

Comment: Make wrapper for route login, admin and wrap this components with this wrapper which will contain style rules.

Comment: It is necessary for the styles to be applied to all blocks on a specific route. Depending on the address, certain styles were applied to the entire page

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean some of the styling of the other components are applyinh on the other route's components?

Try using different classNames instead of using the same classNames which is a big problem I had with react since React is sort of utilizing only one HTML.

You might be interested in css modules to make them scoped and become only locally available instead of using them by priority when available just like what your current css does

[CSS MODULES INFO HERE](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)

Comment: I have an app with more than 10 pages with a unique design(unique style.css file). There will be even more of them in the project, but at the moment there are 10. Connecting more than 10 styles to one page, not only fraught with the appearance of an error, but will simply eat up a lot of memory. I would like the styles for each page to pull up only on the correct route.